# What is an effective way to call jQuery plugins without a wrapper function in global scope from Flash?

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I have checked this question first:
[Calling jQuery Function from Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750039/calling-jquery-function-from-flash)

if we have a jQuery plugin of the following style:

```
(function(){
 $.fn.pluginName = function () {
   var methods = {
     init: function ( options ) {
       var settings = $.extend( {}, {}, options ); // set your own defaults

       $('#flash')[0].initialise(settings);
     },
     initialised: function ( params ) {
       console.log(params);
     }
   };
   var method = 'init', args = [];
   if(0 < arguments.length) {
     if('object' === typeof(arguments[0])) {
       args = arguments;
     } else if('undefined' !== typeof(methods[arguments[0])) {
       args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       args.shift();
       method = arguments[0];
     }
     methods[ method ].apply( this, args );
   }
   return this;
 };
})(jQuery);
```

And let's say we initialise an embedded flash object with id="flash" and then call:

```
$('#controller').pluginName('init',{});
```

and wait for flash to callback.

If I wrote a function, e.g.:

```
function flashCallBack( data ) {
 $('#controller').pluginName('init',data);
}
```

then I could register this function in AS3, but is there a way to call the plugin method directly on the appropriate object without having to write a wrapper function such as the one above in the global namespace?

This didn't work:

```
ExternalInterface.call("$('#controller').pluginName('initialised',"+data+")");
```

as a function name string on flash, nor did this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("$('#controller').pluginName('initialised')",data);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction for how this call can be made directly or clarify if it's just not a supported operation?

Kindest Thanks :)
AE

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution appears to be to wrap your jquery code inside a basic javascript function and then call that top level function from flash using external interface. I found this example and it is said to work:

```
function showNeck () { 
   $('.neck').highlightFade({color:'#FFFF… speed: 5000}); 
}
```

And inside the flash script:

```
import flash.external.*; 
ExternalInterface.call("showNeck", "");
```

Source:

http://old.nabble.com/Call-Jquery-from-Flash--td24959832s27240.html

Comment: Hi Ascension Systems.  Yup, what I would like to do is 'avoid' putting it into the global scope.  Putting it into the global scope allows you to use the third method I put into my question, but the element I'm looking at the moment is now to make the call to a jQuery plugin's method directly instead of using a wrapper.  For example, if it was possible to use ExternalInterface('$.fn.pluginName','initialised',data); I'd try that, but that isn't valid.  Unfortunately, most resources I can find state to use a wrapper, rather than explore if it's not possible or requires an alternative way. Thanks!

Comment: Alright well if you find a solution just be sure to post it! Problem is you're relying on the limitations of the flash ExternalInteface API, which seems to be the issue because the VM cannot (seemingly) accept arguments of this type. I believe this to be the reason why all I could find are solutions that propose wrappers as well.

Comment: I shall =D I'm not sure if there's one out there, but thought I might as well try to get a definitive question and answer for others to help either get them going too or help them move on to making a global function faster and save a bit of time =D Thanks Ascension Systems. I'm wondering if it's possible to call this: window['functionName'] instead of 'functionName' out of curiosity, for the same reason. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function() { $('#controller').pluginName('initialised',"+data+"); }");
```

Kind of like defining (and running) the wrapper function directly in the ExternalInterface.call() rather than defining it in the global space in the page.

I haven't tried it with jQuery plugins specifically, but defining and executing functions like that works, for example like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function() { alert('Hello World!') }");
```

Another *trick* I have used, after seeing it here at SO I believe, is to use the fact that ActionScript supports inline XML (as part of E4X) when you want to write and execute JavaScript like that via ExternalInterface, by writing the JavaScript code inside an XML CDATA block, with line breaks and indentation and so on, rather than concatenating a string of JavaScript, and then execute it in ExternalInterface.call() (as a string), like this:

```
var checkBrowser:XML = <![CDATA[
function() { 
    return {name:navigator.appName, version:navigator.appVersion};
}
]]>;

var browser:Object = ExternalInterface.call(checkBrowser);

trace("Browser: " + browser.name + ", version: " + browser.version);
```

Comment: This one worked for me but only after changing "$" for "jQuery" leaving:

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I think the way to do this, reliably, without having to have a global function is thusly:

```
(function(){
 $.fn.pluginName = function () {
   var methods = {
     init: function ( options ) {
       var settings = $.extend( {}, {}, options ); // set your own defaults

       $('#flash')[0].initialise(settings);
       $(this).click(function(){
          $(this).pluginName('fromFlash');
       });
     },
     initialised: function ( params ) {
       console.log(params);
     },
     callFlash: function(subj,func, data){
        if($('#flash').length > 0){
           $('#flash')[0].callback({
               subj: (subj || 'subjectName'),
               message: {
                  func: (func || '$(\'#selector\').trigger'),
                  data: (data || 'click')
               }
           });
        }
    },
    fromFlash: function(data){
       alert('called from flash');
       console.log(data);
    }
   };
   var method = 'init', args = [];
   if(0 < arguments.length) {
     if('object' === typeof(arguments[0])) {
       args = arguments;
     } else if('undefined' !== typeof(methods[arguments[0])) {
       args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       args.shift();
       method = arguments[0];
     }
     methods[ method ].apply( this, args );
   }
   return this;
 };
})(jQuery);
```

1) Call the method of the plugin to pass it parameters to send to flash:

```
$('#plugin').pluginName('callFlash','subjectName',{
    func:'$(\'#plugin\').trigger',
    data: 'click'
});
```

or you could do something more fun like this:

```
$('#plugin').pluginName('callFlash','subjectName',{
    func: '$(\'#plugin\')[\'pluginName\']',
    data: 'fromFlash'
});
```

2) Call that string from flash as the external callback function string.

```
public function callback ( msg: Object ): void {

    data[0] = msg.message.data; // function callback name
    data[1] = someValue; // from inside flash

    switch ( msg.subject ) {
        case "subjectName":
                    // should push an array to the method name of the jquery plugin
            ExternalInterface.call (msg.message.func, data);
        break;
    }
}
```